# React/Axios/Lambda/DynamoDB: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have an issue with adding data from react app to DynamoDB. I have this code in my react app to submit data from a form to DynamoDB using axios:

```
export const addTodo = createAsyncThunk(
  'todoApp/todos/addTodo',
  async (todo, { dispatch, getState }) => {
    const response = await axios.post('https://aws.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/todoApp-newTodo', todo);
    const data = await response.data;

    dispatch(getTodos());

    return data;
  }
);
```

and my Lambda function is this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-west-2"});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Processing...");
    const params = {
        Item: {
            id: "",
            title: "",
            notes: "",
            startDate: "new Date(2018, 8, 3)",
            dueDate: new Date(2018, 8, 5),
            completed: false,
            starred: false,
            important: false,
            deleted: false,
            labels: [1]
        },
        TableName: "new-todo"
    };
    const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from new Lambda!'),
  };
    
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    })
};
```

When I run the app, and submit the form, I get error message for: unique "key" prop.
I tried following code, and it successfully adds random key in database, but the info I entered in the form, will be gone.

```
this.setState({ id: response.data.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding unique value with "key" property?

And you can use this code for update state.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, // rest of the object
    value: 'something' // the value we want to update
}}))
```